# Create JSON object from Array and Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have this JSON Object:

```
{
  "columnNames": [
    "Incident ID",
    "IncidentType"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "3599590",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ],
    [
      "3599601",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I would like to convert that object in Javascript to this object:

```
{
  reportResults: [{
      "Incident ID": "3599590",
      "IncidentType": "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    },
    {
      "Incident ID": "3599591",
      "IncidentType": "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have tried using the push function in the following example:

```
VWA_Output = {
  "columnNames": [
    "Incident ID",
    "IncidentType"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "3599590",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ],
    [
      "3599601",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ]
  ]
};

JSTest_JSON_Var1 = {
  reportResults: []
};
for (i in VWA_Output.rows) {
  for (var j in VWA_Output.rows[i]) {
    var key = VWA_Output.columnNames[j];
    var value = VWA_Output.rows[i][j]
    JSTest_JSON_Var1.reportResults.push({
      [key]: value
    });

  }
}
console.log(JSTest_JSON_Var1);
```

However, it seems to create the the object like this with the collection as an individual array element:

```
{
  [{
    "reportResults": [{
        "Incident ID": "3599590"
      }, {
        "IncidentType": "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
      }
    },
    {
      "Incident ID": "3599591"
    },
    {
      "IncidentType": "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    }
  }]
}
```

I would like the collection of columns and rows to be a single record collection in the array:

```
{
  "reportResults": [{
    "Incident ID": "3599590",
    "IncidentType": "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
  }, {
    "Incident ID": "3599591",
    "IncidentType": "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
  }]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your attempted method could work if you make an empty object before the innerloop. Then inside the innerloop assign the key and value to it as `obj[key] = value` and finally outside the innerloop push that object to `JSTest_JSON_Var1.reportResults`. But I think you should just go with the more readable answers provided below.

Comment: All of the methods provided worked via my testing in the browsers. I'm using the Javascript component in Oracle SOA Suite to perform the parse and object rebuild and unfortunately it doesn't like the map function calls (the component is based on the Mozilla Rhino Javascript engine). I ended up doing aerial301's suggestion and changed up my original code to push in the outer loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the `reportResults` all at once - have its contents be an array mapped from the `rows`, where you use the index of the column name you're iterating over to access the appropriate row value. I'd use `Object.fromEntries` to keep things concise.

```js
const input = {
  "columnNames": [
    "Incident ID",
    "IncidentType"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "3599590",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ],
    [
      "3599601",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ]
  ]
};
const output = {
  reportResults: input.rows.map(row => Object.fromEntries(
    input.columnNames.map((name, i) => [name, row[i]])
  ))
};
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your example data is in `data`:

```
const result = {
  "reportResults" : data.rows.map(row => {
    return {
      [data.columnNames[0]]: row[0],
      [data.columnNames[1]]: row[1]
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

that is my solution:

```js
var data = {
  "columnNames": [
    "Incident ID",
    "IncidentType"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "3599590",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ],
    [
      "3599601",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ]
  ]
}

var reportResults = data.rows.map((row) => 
    Object.assign({}, ...row.map((cell, i) => ({ [data.columnNames[i]]: cell})))
)

console.log({reportResults})
```

Not optimal, but short)

Answer (score 1):

See my comments above. Every answer provided worked in the browser, but not in the SOA Suite Javascript component I am using. The component didn't like the map function calls. Thanks again for all of the responses.

Here is what did work with the Oracle SOA Suite JS component:

```
process.VWA_Output = {
  "columnNames": [
    "Incident ID",
    "IncidentType"
  ],
  "rows": [
    [
      "3599590",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ],
    [
      "3599601",
      "Telecommuting/VWA Empl- Initiate"
    ]
  ]
};
process.JSTest_JSON_Var1 = { 
  reportResults: [] 
}; 

for (i in process.VWA_Output.rows) { 
  const row = new Object(); 
  for (var j in process.VWA_Output.rows[i]) { 
    var key = process.VWA_Output.columnNames[j]; 
    var value = process.VWA_Output.rows[i][j]; 
    row[key] = value; 
  } 
  process.JSTest_JSON_Var1.reportResults.push(row); 
}
```